# How do I make the AI trade for maximum profit?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I'm using *AoE II: The Conquerors* with the 1.0c patch, and I'm wondering if it is possible for two of my AIs to trade but for the max possible profit. For example, if the AIs had conquered half the map, then is it possible for them to move their markets to the corners of the map so it's the max possible profit?

Also, is there something like direct unit control (DUC) in patch 1.0c? I've heard that the AIs have little control over the armies in this patch. For example, is it possible for the knights to guard the trebuchet when attacking?

Comment: Don't think AIs are programmed with the concept of maximizing profit, because they can't have an understanding of what is safe and what isn't. The markets just get dropped at random locations. @DUC I never heard of such a thing.